# How to retrieve current value that has assigned after button click in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In ASP.NET I could use sessions for it but for windows form how can I get current value to which I can add + 1?

After btnPrintToken click it would override, re-run the code, I want it to keep the last entered value(LastTokenNumberIssued) and for it to add + 1 and so on so it will update the queue.

```
private void btnPrintToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Queue<int> queueTokens = new Queue<int>();

    lblStatus.Text = "There are " + queueTokens.Count.ToString() +
        " customers before you in the queue";

    int LastTokenNumberIssued = // Not sure how to retrieve current value what it was after nextTokenNumberTobeIssued.
    int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = LastTokenNumberIssued + 1;
    LastTokenNumberIssued = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;

    queueTokens.Enqueue(nextTokenNumberTobeIssued);
    AddTokensToListBox(queueTokens);
}

private void AddTokensToListBox(Queue<int> queueTokens)
{
    listTokens.Items.Clear();
    foreach (int token in queueTokens)
    {
        listTokens.Items.Add(token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the current value to which I can add +1". The current value of what? The number of times you pressed the button? The number of integers in the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your LastTokenNumberIssued outside the method:

```
public YourWindow 
{
   int LastTokenNumberIssued;

   private void btnPrintToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      int nextTokenNumberIssued;

      LastTokenNumberIssued = LastTokenNumberIssued++;
      nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = LastTokenNumberIssued;
   }
}
```

If you create LastTokenNumberIssued inside the method, it will get  overridden everytime you click the button because its value is lost when the method returns.

Check [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/method) for more info on method scope.

Comment: Yeah, i did understand that it will be overridden after every click but why in hell i didn't figure it out to make first values outside of the button method. Damn i feel so stupid, thank you a lot!

Comment: @Harri, please mark the answer. And it's fine, sometimes we are so tired of trying to solve a problem that it looks more complex than it is in fact.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, is by defining these variables `nextTokenNumberTobeIssued`, `LastTokenNumberIssued` before the `btnPrintToken_Click` method, something like this:

```
int LastTokenNumberIssued = 0; //give it a default value here.
int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = 0; //give it a default value here.

private void btnPrintToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
    nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = LastTokenNumberIssued + 1;
    LastTokenNumberIssued = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;
    ...
}
```

This way each time the user click the button `PrintToken`, you will have the `LastTokenNumberIssued` holds the previous click.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int LastTokenNumberIssued = 0; //here will be the start value
 private void btnPrintToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Queue<int> queueTokens = new Queue<int>();

    lblStatus.Text = "There are " + queueTokens.Count.ToString() +
        " customers before you in the queue";

    int nextTokenNumberTobeIssued = LastTokenNumberIssued + 1;
    LastTokenNumberIssued = nextTokenNumberTobeIssued;

    queueTokens.Enqueue(nextTokenNumberTobeIssued);
    AddTokensToListBox(queueTokens);
}

private void AddTokensToListBox(Queue<int> queueTokens)
{
    listTokens.Items.Clear();
    foreach (int token in queueTokens)
    {
        listTokens.Items.Add(token.ToString());
    }
}
```